# How to restart updated animation after dynamically changing keyframes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, typescript, animation

I'm trying to create a marquee (yes, I've done LOTS of searching on that topic first) using animated `text-indent`. I prefer this solution over others I've tried, like using translation 100%, which causes text to leak out beyond the boundaries of my marquee.

I've been trying to follow this example here: https://www.jonathan-petitcolas.com/2013/05/06/simulate-marquee-tag-in-css-and-javascript.html

...which I've updated a bit, doing it in TypeScript, using API updates (`appendRule` instead of `insertRule`) and dropping concerns about old browser support.

The problem is that the animation restarts using the old keyframe rules -- the step described by the comment "re-assign the animation (to make it run)" doesn't work.

I've looked at what's going on in a debugger, and the rules are definitely being changed -- old rules deleted, new rules added. But it's as if the old rules are cached somewhere, and they aren't being cleared out.

Here's my current CSS:

```
#marquee {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 170px;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: midnightblue;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 2px 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: none;
}

#marquee:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes marquee-0 {
  0% {
    text-indent: 450px;
  }

  100% {
    text-indent: -500px;
  }
}
```

And the relevant section of my TypeScript:

```
function updateMarqueeAnimation() {
  const marqueeRule = getKeyframesRule('marquee-0');

  if (!marqueeRule)
    return;

  marquee.css('animation', 'unset');

  const element = marquee[0];
  const textWidth = getTextWidth(marquee.text(), element);
  const padding = Number(window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('padding-left').replace('px', '')) +
                  Number(window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('padding-right').replace('px', ''));
  const offsetWidth = element.offsetWidth;

  if (textWidth + padding <= offsetWidth)
    return;

  marqueeRule.deleteRule('0%');
  marqueeRule.deleteRule('100%');
  marqueeRule.appendRule('0% { text-indent: ' + offsetWidth + 'px; }');
  marqueeRule.appendRule('100% { text-indent: -' + textWidth + 'px; }');

  setTimeout(() => marquee.css('animation', 'marquee-0 15s linear infinite'));
}
```

I've tried a number of tricks so far to get around this problem, including things like cloning the marquee element and replacing it with its own clone, and none of that has helped -- the animation continues to run as if the original stylesheet values are in effect, so the scrolling of the marquee doesn't adapt to different widths of text.

The next thing I'll probably try is dynamically creating new keyframes objects instead of editing the rules inside of an existing keyframes object, but that's a messy solution I'd rather avoid if anyone has a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get my marquee working, and it did involved dynamically adding and removing keyframes rules from a stylesheet, but that wasn't as painful or ugly as I thought it might be.

```
let animationStyleSheet: CSSStyleSheet;
let keyframesIndex = 0;
let lastMarqueeText = '';

function updateMarqueeAnimation(event?: Event) {
  const newText = marquee.text();

  if (event === null && lastMarqueeText === newText)
    return;

  lastMarqueeText = newText;
  marquee.css('animation', 'none');

  const element = marquee[0];
  const textWidth = getTextWidth(newText, element);
  const padding = Number(window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('padding-left').replace('px', '')) +
                  Number(window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('padding-right').replace('px', ''));
  const offsetWidth = element.offsetWidth;

  if (textWidth + padding <= offsetWidth)
    return;

  if (!animationStyleSheet) {
    $('head').append('<style id="marquee-animations" type="text/css"></style>');
    animationStyleSheet = ($('#marquee-animations').get(0) as HTMLStyleElement).sheet as CSSStyleSheet;
  }

  if (animationStyleSheet.cssRules.length > 0)
    animationStyleSheet.deleteRule(0);

  const keyframesName = 'marquee-' + keyframesIndex++;
  const keyframesRule = `@keyframes ${keyframesName} { 0% { text-indent: ${offsetWidth}px } 100% { text-indent: -${textWidth}px; } }`;
  const seconds = (textWidth + offsetWidth) / 100;

  animationStyleSheet.insertRule(keyframesRule, 0);
  marquee.css('animation', `${keyframesName} ${seconds}s linear infinite`);
}
```

There's other stuff going on here not needed for a general solution. One thing is that this method is called for two reasons: The window is being resized, or an update to the marquee text has been made. I always want to update when the window is resized, but otherwise I don't want to update the animation if the text hasn't changed, otherwise it could unnecessarily reset when someone is trying to read it.

The other thing is that I don't want text to scroll at all if it happens to fit nicely without scrolling.